# Не работает запрос SQL c поиском по тексту

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Мне нужен запрос с выборкой объектов по условию, наличия текста в колонках.

Пробую такой запрос:

```
SELECT `id`, `title`, `description`, `closed` 
FROM `polls` 
WHERE `id` != 1001 AND (
  (`title` LIKE '%asda%') OR 
  (`description` LIKE '%asda%')) 
ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Где проверяю наличие в колонках `title` и `description` строки asda, но на выходе получаю все объекты из таблицы, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вы не можете их все получить, максимум 10 ;)

Comment: судя по запросу все выбираемые объекты действительно содержат asda хотя бы в одной из колонок

Comment: Приведите пример хотя бы одной строчки, которая по вашим ожиданиям не должны была попасть в результат.